# Is it possible to convert mesh islands to instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to convert mesh islands to instances, so that each instance will have each island?

[image]

Comment: Maybe even a better method to turn mesh islands into instances:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297733/8282

Comment: ^ To the pondering of above comment, no it wasn't. It yielded 10secs on my scenario. The result .blend of the answer below was only 6secs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Blender 4.0 it is possible with loops:

RaccoonGraphics gave the nodes in [here](https://twitter.com/Genesis_2303/status/1672989821172629511?s=20) in Twitter.

[image]

[image]

## Note from OP:

I think that writing index into all vertices is very expensive, so I made an update to this node tree:

[image]

## .blend (The optimized version above, Blender 4.0):

[image]

Comment: oh, that's interesting

Comment: @Crantisz Thank you for the improvement, I didn't know it is possible to do some kind of 'pull requests' into people's answers :D Maybe I should some day do the same, as well. When a good situation occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Here the shortest way. Each separate node in the column separates island with index=0 from the leftover of previous separation.
And the last node separates two last islands.

[image: simple separation islands to instances]

Answer (score 1):

well...i am sure that's not the way you want, but that's one way - but a tedious one:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see, quite clever way but limited to number of copies of the node group.

Comment: Yep - hopefully Robin or Quellenform come up with a better one 

Comment: Unfortunately, the only answer to the question "Is it possible to convert mesh islands to instances?" is: No, not possible. Maybe there is another way to the goal, but for that you would have to know the goal. @Crantisz ?