# Stepped playback in viewport?

Tags: geometry-nodes

We have an option called step in the frame range settings of the render output properties. It skips the number of frames specified. Now that works only for renders. Is there any way such a thing can be emulated in the viewport?

The thing is substeps for simulation nodes are going to take a few thousand years to arrive. Until then I am sticking with the increasing frame rate and using step workaround. Now even though this works for the final render, this absolutely messes up my head while in the viewport. Coz this gives us a much slower playback. And I can only guess what the final speed might be. So yeah, is it possible to use something like step within the viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### X Problem

Unfortunately, solving the problem in title doesn't fix your problem in the description… If you render this setup:

[image]

without playing it in viewport first, with a step of $2$, the cube will move in a single direction:

[image]

### Y Problem

> substeps for simulation nodes are going to take a few thousand years to arrive.

It's already easy to implement in B4.0α, using the *Repeat Zone*:

[image]

Incrementing the iterator `i` serves as an example, but maintaining a step number like that could be useful in most setups…

### Example

Using my mesh splitter from here:

[Geometry Nodes: Mesh Boolean / Mesh Splitting Repeat Loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297733/60486)

We can modify it according to the rules described above:

[image]

The custom group with the inner loop changed slightly as well, in order to support the displacement:

[image]

And now it will cut much faster:

[image]

[image]