# Geo nodes setup for mesh that is procedurally fragmented to explode

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I am working on this project where I am procedurally fragmenting a sphere. After it is fragmented (The process happens in a simulation zone).

I want the fragments to fly apart from one another and rotate in all directions, kind of an explosion but very slowly. After I output the mesh from the simulation zone.

The only thing I managed to do was scale elements independently. But never move them apart.
Here is the blend file:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fu3edqqhfirthuqfp5li4/Glass-partice-simulation.blend?rlkey=krbrn28urq0iz0gmym1bn7n4t&dl=0

[image]

Comment: what sense does it make to map range an island index (which is always positive) from -3/8 to -1/8 and then putting that in a boolean input?

Comment: i recommend providing a blend file so we know what you did and don't have to ask in comments.

Comment: Sure, I will attach it to the post.

Comment: Chris may have more luck, but it's very hard to reverse-engineer a node-group / code which has no commentary, description in frames, or in your post.. and that can lead to folks giving up before they start trying to help. My advice: Strip the problem down to its simplest possible form, with the fewest possible parts. Eliminate everything in your scene that isn't relevant. Use descriptive names for objects / node groups. Describe to us your strategy for achieving the effect, in plain language, and where it's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Robin, I will certainly update the file to make it more readable.

Comment: [Geometry Nodes: Mesh Boolean / Mesh Splitting Repeat Loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297733/60486)

Comment: Thanks, Markus, I guess that solves it!

Comment: @Chris, It's the only way it would select all the fragments, that's why it starts from -3, although the indexing starts from 0. Found it strange too. I changed it eventually.

Comment: @Greatest notice how in my setup the donut splits into thinner and thinner needles, because I only rotate the cutters and don't offset (translate, move) them. But patching that should be trivial… Of course at some point you have to ask yourself with what shape (randomly displaced primitive?) and how positioned (near the average position ≅ center of mass?) do you want it to be for a professional effect…

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I am going through it now, trying to figure out how to make it move apart faster. It's a clever setup.