# Create Seamless Fractures off a mesh

Tags: cell-fracture

I require a quick workflow to create Seamless fractures. The Default Cell-Fracture addon doesn't seem to allow for that...

[image]
Steps to Reproduce

1. Create new Scene in blender
2. if not already enable Cell Fracture addon
3. select Cube -> F3 -> Cell Fracture
4. in settings set margin to 0 and apply
5. Go into Material Preview and seach for visible seams between the fractures

Comment: [Geometry Nodes: Mesh Boolean / Mesh Splitting Repeat Loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297733/60486)

Comment: The problem isn't just with CF (although it has a problem as well, it's getting some precision problems and not handling them well.)  The main problem is with the Eevee renderer, used for material view, which seems to have an issue with seeing around edges when it comes to world lighting.

Comment: Eevee ain't the problem because with the solution proposed form Markus, can do seamless fractures which are not visible in Eevee, thanks Markus!