# Move select linked based on proximity using Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, selection-tools

I would like to offset certain elements in the y direction of this mesh based on the proximity relative to the wire framed cube. All the hexagon elements belong to the same mesh but are separate regarding the vertices. This is the desired effect:

[image]

I've managed to displace the vertices like this using the geometry proximity node:

[image]

But I would like to move the entire part. This is my current geometry nodes setup:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the average position per mesh island and use it as the source for the Geometry Proximity.

To calculate, divide the sum of positions by the amount of points, values that can be obtained using the Accumulate Field node with island index as Group ID.

[image: node tree]

Result:

[image]

[image]$\small\color{DarkOrange}{|}\hspace{2pt}\color{gray}{{\tiny\text{V}}\text{ 3.6.5}}\hspace{2pt}\color{DarkOrange}{|}$

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So first what you will need to do is to convert your mesh to instances. 
It's a bit complicated process and it costs a lot. There is already a solution how to make it in blender 4.0. 
**You can read about it more here:**
[Is it possible to convert mesh islands to instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275988/is-it-possible-to-convert-mesh-islands-to-instances)

And part, where you made a proxmimity object is correct, so the whole setup will look something like this.

[image]

[image]