# Geometry Nodes: Bend each instance to curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

I have a very simple setup and what i want is to bend each instance to the curve shape after "instance on points" node. I've seen setups here where you first make an array and then bend it to curve using set poisiton node, but this is not the way in my case, because later i want to rotate each instance individually using proximity node, which does not work well with an array solution. Thank you! [image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to bend geometry with geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes)

Comment: Saw it. It does, but it does not allow me to rotate each instance individually after they instances are bent.

Comment: You cannot bend instances differently because they are instances (they are all the same). To do this, you would have to realize them and rotate their points around an individual center. So your question is actually a duplicate of the linked answer and is actually aimed at how you can capture this individual center and rotate the points.

Answer (score 0):

As quellenform pointed, you cannot bend instances. Instance is an object inside object, so in order to get points information you have to realize instances, so that they will be converted into meshes with points, edges and faces. After that you can rotate points as you want, instances are not necessary. For example, this set up:

[image]

I've used the setup from suggested question [how to bend geometry with geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes) and added node *Set position* to it.

Position is calculated by rotating the position vector around the median point of each mesh island.

As you see, it is possible to rotate the mesh island itself, using several additional nodes.

Making instances from mesh islands is harder, But if you want you can find the solution here: [Is it possible to convert mesh islands to instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275988/is-it-possible-to-convert-mesh-islands-to-instances)